# How to import duplicate package structures and classes in a Java application

Tags: java, package

I am wondering if there is a way around this problem without changing the package structures.

I have 2 similar web apps with identical package structures. Classes are the named the same as well.

I would like to use both versions of these packages and create objects from the classes in a third app.

The reason for this and as an example, is that I want to create a single web app that manages user accounts for these 2 other web apps. The package structure for both is `com/mycompany/User.java`

The problem (as I see it) is that I can't just have these 2 apps package structures in my classpath and have a way to differentiate between them when creating objects.

i.e.

When creating a `User` object, how can I specify that I want to create it from package 1 or package 2. I don't want to refactor the code or change the way the apps packages are structured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't do this, in java a class its identified by his package and his name, you cannot have two classes in the same package with the same name.

In fact its really a very bad practice, why you have two things with exact the same name representing two different things?. Change your package an include the application name, at least, in the name:

```
com/mycompany/myapplication/User.java
```

Comment: You can use multiple classloaders to solve this, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @Brian Roach Could you expand on your comment and make it an answer? If only for a temporary solution, this would be very helpful.

Comment: @Matthew Honestly, no. Because it would be a *bad* answer. The right answer is to refactor the source correctly.

Comment: @anyone I was thinking that using a class loader might help me get around the problem but not sure where to start. I appreciate the answer that is the "right" approach but it's just not the answer I am looking for. Yes, I'm a bit stubborn but I'll accept this one if nobody can provide a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that in any recommended way.
You should refactor it.

If there is no chance of refactoing, e.g for legal reasons, then try this approach:

Although I will not recommend it, you could use `Proguard` to obfuscate only the class User, and use a predefined `obfuscation.map` and name it there User2.
The output is a new jar file, where the class User has a new name.

Example of such an obfuscation.map entry:

```
com.company.transform.TransformException -> ad.d:
```

Comment: You *can* use multiple classloaders to solve this, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @BrianRoach, yes I reformulated and gave a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use 2 classloaders loading from different .jar files (for a sophisticated solution check out [OSGi](http://moi.vonos.net/java/osgi-classloaders/)). But it's going to be very confusing, and I would recommend renaming/repackaging.